# Need to Compare Dates in SSRS with Year Parameter and hardcoded Month

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, date-format

I need to compare a date v. "Today" in a MM/YY format and then if true it will execute the rest and if not it will be blank. This is what I have so far but I get the "'Interger' to type 'Date' is not valid...

```
=IIF(Format(Month(10) & Parameters!Year.Value, "MM/YY") < Format(Today,"MM/YY"),
IIF(Fields!Milestone.Value="Average Number of Days Milestones were Early", 
FormatNumber(Fields!Oct.Value,0), IIF(Fields!Oct.Value = 0, "", 
FormatNumber(Fields!Oct.Value,0))),"")
```

I really appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I kept playing around and got it to work

```
=IIF(FormatDateTime(CDATE("11" & "/" & Parameters!
Year.Value),DateFormat.ShortDate) < FormatDateTime
(Today,DateFormat.ShortDate),IIF(Fields!Milestone.Value="Average Number of Days Milestones were Early", 
FormatNumber(Fields!Oct.Value,0), IIF(Fields!Oct.Value = 0, "", 
FormatNumber(Fields!Oct.Value,0))),"")
```